# Setting up hotkeys for launcher likes mutate and albert doesn't works properly

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

hotkeys doesn't works except keys like (F1, F2, F3).
But in guake terminal it work really work really well(like alt + space). What might be the problem?

Comment: You probably need to be more explicit.  Where are you setting the hotkeys?  I can set hotkeys in xorg, shell, display manger, and window manager.  And that is not even counting any actual applications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the following

https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/faq/#error-key-x-could-not-be-registered

Maybe you should be less sparingly with information. Run it from terminal show the output, tell something about your envrionment etc.